# Apache 2.4 Mac Yosemite Won't Start

Tags: macos, apache

I've recently upgraded to Yosemite on a Mac, which comes bundled with Apache 2.4.  I'm trying to start up a previously-working apache (2.2) set of configs and getting the following:

```
$ sudo apachectl
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I've tried with and without the sudo.

Common causes of this problem that I've ruled out include:

- Duplicate 'Listen' statements for the same port.  (Also would show up as a port binding failure in my experience)
- Something's already listening on port 80/443.  (Checked via netstats, clean)
- Disk space near full.  (Have plenty of space)

Curiously, I lack a ports.conf which I see referenced in many older threads.  Is this a file I should add?

Now, in order to get this far, I had to update my httpd.conf to uncomment modules that I was using.  However, I double-checked that I didn't have duplicate listen statements (I still could have missed one, but I'd expect to get a port-binding exception on that port #).

I've seen comments to run the Apache .exe, but obviously being on a Mac I don't have one.  I don't know if there's a .app I can run, I could not find one.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Including the results of `sudo apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myname.mysite.test (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost myname.mysite.test (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost controlpanel.myname.mysite.test (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:50)
*:443                  secure.myname.mysite.test (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:55)
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70
Group: name="_www" id=70
```

Comment: Side-note: Is this a new syntax? If you want to start the apachectl, isnt the correct syntax `sudo apachectl start` ?

Comment: Try `sudo apachectl -S` to make sure it's parsing your config right, or `sudo apachectl -e debug -k start` to see startup errors. If no stop, start, configtest, etc. arguments are passed to apachectl, it just passes everything directly to httpd, so it should still work even with no arguments.

Comment: @miken32: When I run `sudo apachectl -e debug -k start`I get the same message as above after several messages cycling through each of the modules I want, which all load successfully.  No new error messages or information.

Everything looks correct on `sudo apachectl -S`.

@mattias: When I run `sudo apachectl start` apache appears to start, but it never ends up listening on the port I need it to, so I suspect it's just failing silently.

Comment: @miken32 I also included the results of the -S.